# Get the list of all cube names using DMVs when cubes are unprocessed

Tags: sql, sql-server, olap-cube, ssas-tabular, dmv

I want to get the list of all cube names on an SSAS Server. I am using this query to retrieve them:

```
select *
from $System.MDSCHEMA_CUBES
where CUBE_SOURCE = 1
```

My goal is to know which cubes are processed or unprocessed. But the problem with the above query is that it is missing **unprocessed** cubes, so that I cannot retrieve the complete list of all cubes on the server.

Is there a way to retrieve the missing cube name even if it is unprocessed ?

Comment: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4219/sql-server-analysis-services-cube-processing-status-report/

Comment: I omit to say I am looking for a solution that also works for SSAS Tabular.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe look at Partitions to see which need processing?

```
select * from $SYSTEM.TMSCHEMA_PARTITIONS where [STATE] <> 1;
```

[2.2.5.6 Partition Object - State](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/sql_server_protocols/ms-ssas-t/81badb81-31a8-482b-ae16-5fc9d8291d9e)

Ready (1) – The partition is queryable and has up-to-date data.

NoData (3) – The partition is queryable but has no data. This state applies only to partitions with a type other than Calculated.

CalculationNeeded (4) – The partition is not queryable and needs to be refreshed (that is, recalculated) to become functional. This state applies only to partitions of the type Calculated.

SemanticError (5) – The partition is in an error state because of an invalid expression and is not queryable. This state applies only to partitions of the type Calculated.

EvaluationError (6) – The partition is in an error state because of an error during expression evaluation. The partition is not queryable. This state applies only to partitions of the type Calculated.

DependencyError (7) – The partition is in an error state because some of its calculation dependencies are in an error state. The partition is not queryable. This state applies only to partitions of the type Calculated.

Incomplete (8) - Some parts of the partition have no data, and the partition needs to be refreshed to bring the data in. The partition is queryable. This state applies only to partitions of a type other than Calculated.

SyntaxError (9) - The partition is in an error state because of a syntax error in its expression. The partition is not queryable. This state applies only to partitions of the type Calculated.